# Espresso, testing happy path with login screen

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test my Happy path based on Espresso. My flow is like this:

`SplashActivity -> Activity_1 -> Activity_2 -> Activity_3 -> Activity_4.`

There is a button in `Activity_1` that directs user to `Activity_2` if user has not logged in otherwise `Activity_3` for Booking something.

My tests passes if app goes in this direction `SplashActivity -> Activity_1 -> Activity_3 ->...`. However I'm getting exception, `android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching:` when user has not logged in and therefore app goes in this way `SplashActivity -> Activity_1 -> Activity_2 ->...`.

This is obvious because my test expects `Activity_3` while `Activity_2` is visible.

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MinHappyPathTest
{
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<Activity_1> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(Activity_1.class);

    private Activity_1 mActivity_1;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        mActivity_1 = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void HappyPathMinimumTest() throws InterruptedException
    {    
        // Wait to everything settles down (few animations there)
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // On mActivity_1 press the button
        onView(withId(R.id.btnNext)).perform(click());

        // On mActivity_3        onView(withId(R.id.editText)).perform(typeText(destination_short_name), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());
        Thread.sleep(1000); // to results displays
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view), isDisplayed()))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));

        // Other tests...
    }
}
```

Two questions I have:

1. How to put if statement based on the activity is visible after `Activity_1`?
2. Based on what I have found unlike Unit Testing that you are able to pick a class and perform testing against it, it is not possible to do same thing in Espresso. For example I directly run `mActivity_4` and test it since when app launches `mActivity_1` displays by default and I get `NoMatchingViewException`. Am I right? I actually tested and looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are receiving NoMatchingViewException because you are using Thread.sleep. It is not working with Espresso. You should use IdlingResources to notify Espresso when it can continue. See example of such IdlingResource implementation here - http://droidtestlab.com/delay.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I read about islingResource before and thanks for the link but `Thread.sleep()` works well for me. I have an SMS confirmation screen that waits 30S to receive a code via SMS. Even in this screen my `Thread.sleep(31000);` works well. I have used this waiting method widely across my happy path and didn't see a problem. Thanks  again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way that I can check what activity is being displayed so I decided to use `if` statement in the way I'm using in Activity like this:

```
@Test
public void HappyPathMinimumTest() throws InterruptedException
{    
    // Wait to everything settles down (few animations there)
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // On Activity_1 press the button
    onView(withId(R.id.btnNext)).perform(click());

    // Display login screen if required (Activity_2)
    if (myCondition)
    {
        // tests of Login activity...
    }

    // On mActivity_3        onView(withId(R.id.editText)).perform(typeText(destination_short_name), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());
    Thread.sleep(1000); // to results displays
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view), isDisplayed()))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));

    // Other tests...
}
```